# switch not activating function

Tags: javascript, html

This is supposed to display different things when a different OS is detected, but it shows nothing. I know the function works, because if I call the function without a switch it shows. Also, the sublime text links were just a test. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Mac(){
                document.write("<a href=\"http:\/\/www.sublimetext.com\/\">Sublime Text<\/a>");
                document.write("This is the Mac instructions";)
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Windows(){
                document.write("<a href=\"http:\/\/www.sublimetext.com\/\">Sublime Text<\/a>");
                document.write("This is the Windows instructions";)
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Lesson 1: Prerequisites</h1>
            <script>
                switch(OSName) {
                    case "Mac":
                        Mac()
                        break;
                    default:
                        Windows()
                }
            </script>
    </div>
```

And I am getting OSName from above:

```
            <script>
            var OSName="Unknown OS";
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="Mac";
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
            if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
            </script>
```

And I know that works because I can display it with:

```
document.write('Your operating system has been determined as '+OSName +'.');
```

Comment: Please do not post code on SO which generates console errors (unless the console error itself is what you have a question about). Do you know what the console is? Did you view it? Did you see any errors? Do you think that you can post every typo and minor syntax error to Stack Overflow to have people here find it for you, when your computer is already telling you where it is, if you would only bother to look? If you don't know what the console is, then please stop programming right now and don't start again until you've studied and understood it thoroughly.

Comment: I also strongly doubt your assertion that "if I call the function without switch it shows", because the function contains a syntax error, and would never execute (actually, the first line would execute, then it would choke on the second line). By the way, is there any special reason you're escaping the `/` characters in the URL? It's not necessary. Is there any reason you're using separate `<script>` tags? It's not necessary. Any reason you're not indenting your code properly? It makes it hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Your navigator if statements need to be above the switch, then it will work as expected. You also need to fix the document.write end brackets - you should also have `;` after the function brackets.. i.e `Mac();`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know for sure if this may be the problem but maybe in your mac and your windows functions you should may be replace this code:

```
document.write("This is the Mac instructions";)    
document.write("This is the Windows instructions";)
```

with

```
document.write("This is the Mac instructions");    
document.write("This is the Windows instructions");
```

The semicolon is probably the issue, document.write might be thinking you're ending the statement before the closing parentheses

"document.write" is typically used for testing purposes when writing JavaScript. But document.write has issues and is outdated. In order to appropriately test nowadays you should use "console.log". Your code should then look like this:

```
console.log("This is the Mac instructions");    
console.log("This is the Windows instructions");
```

Keep in mind in order to see an output you will need to open the console in your browsers "Developer Tools".

If you want to use the strings appropriately for printing in html, you may need to use returns or attach the string directly to an html element. I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? This was an answer that should have solved the issue the op was having.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in your `Mac()` and `Windows()` functions.
Instead of

```
document.write("This is the Mac instructions";)
document.write("This is the Windows instructions";)
```

write

```
document.write("This is the Mac instructions");
document.write("This is the Windows instructions");
```

Please note that you should not put every function in different `<script>` tag. Here is working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kyqLjqb3/7/

Comment: Why downvoted? I suppose that it is because of giving answer that is so obvious for someone with experience. I understand that person who ask is beginner, but we all were beginners. If something is obvious for person who answer it may not be obvious for person who ask the question.